# 404 not found error without https:// when type https its working fine cloudflare problem i think

Tags: http-status-code-404, cloudflare

when i type http://profilepics.in its my website i am getting 404 not found error. Here is the link : https://profilepics.in/error-page.jpg. 
When i type https:// its working fine. I am using cloud flare please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: can't reproduce. `http://profilepics.in/` 301 redirects to `https://profilepics.in/` which returns status code 200

Comment: ok thanks. but why i'm getting this error- i'm tested in mozilla, chrome......